# 74HCT4094 shift register not working

Tags: shift-register

I am trying to drive 2 7-segment displays. I dont know why but one of the 7-segment displays is much dimmer than the other. I am using ESP32 module.Code that i am running :

```
int Data =  4;  
int Latch = 15; 
int Clock= 12; 

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(Data,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Latch,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Clock,OUTPUT);


}

void loop() {
    Serial.println("here");
    digitalWrite(Latch,LOW);
    shiftOut(Data,Clock,MSBFIRST,0b00000000);
    shiftOut(Data,Clock,MSBFIRST,0b11111111);
    digitalWrite(Latch,HIGH);
    delay(3000);
}
```

[image: Stacked shift registers]

Comment: After transferring internal data to outputs, you should return LATCH to LOW. You should add also a time ON then OFF, in a repeating loop, as in Multiplex systems if a limiting resistor for each Led is not used (use OE pin).

Answer (score 2):

The problem was with the soldering of the component to the board. The V+ was not soldered properly, other pins were fine.

Answer (score 1):

With a partial schematic I can only take a SWAG. I assume the 74HCT4094D drive the LEDs directly. Looking at the Nexperia data sheet Rev. 9 — 22 October 2021 it shows a max of 25mA per output but it shows a max of 50mA for the chip supply and ground. You need to add resistors or drivers to the outputs. The internal bond wires act as low value resistors and can fry. This internal resistance could be causing one of them to be dimmer.